# Can a transit visa be issued at the airport?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, malaysia

A colleague of mine traveled to the Philippines via Malaysia. Apparently, the terminal for his onward flight is 4km away from the arrival terminal. He is Pakistani and doesn't have a transit visa and, as a result, can't make the connection. He was told to book another flight which does leave from the terminal he is already in. He would have to pay an additional $500 US for the ticket.

Can a transit visa be issued at the airport to go to that terminal if the person is willing to pay?

Comment: @ahmat talat , what is his nationality , also destination is Philippines and transit in Kuala Lumpur Malaysia or another airport?

Comment: nationality is pakistani and transit is in Kuala Lumpur.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This was more than 7 months ago. I was thinking of making the same trip but abu dhabi as my connecting terminal so thought i'd ask

Comment: @ahmadtalat So your question is about Abu Dhabi? Edit your question to reflect that then

Comment: @Crazydre no its not. I just wanted to clarify my friend's situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pakistani nationals can transit in Malaysia without a visa provided:

- TWOV cannot be offered to passenger sponsored by airlines other than
  Malaysia Airlines and Air Asia. At present only MAS and Air Asia have
  agreed and accepted all terms and conditions imposed by the Malaysian
  Government.
- TWOV facility is not available at entry point other than Kuala Lumpur
  International Airport (KLIA) and Low Cost Carrier Terminal (LCCT)

which means your friend will not be allowed to change airports in Kuala Lumpur. It is only possible to transit without a visa if your friend travels on Malaysia Airlines or Air Asia.

Source:[Ministry Of Foreign Affairs Malaysia](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information)

> Can't a transit visa be issued at the airport to go to that terminal
>   if the person is willing to pay?

No, no  visa will be issued at the airport for Pakistani Nationals if they are planning to change the terminals. However, there is a exception if your friend has a valid visas from:

Source:[Ministry Of Foreign Affairs Malaysia](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information)

- Australia,  New Zealand, United States of America,   Japan, China, Taiwan and South Korea.
- a max. time of 120 hours, arriving at   and departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines (MH) or  Air Asia (AK). When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is  permitted to leave the transit area

If your friend meets the above requirement, then he will be able to change airports; otherwise, I am afraid he will have to change tickets.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=MY&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=tw&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of a valid visa issued by
>   Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea
>   (Rep.), New Zealand or USA to nationals of Pakistan residing in country of nationality holding confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 120 hours, arriving at and departing from Kuala Lumpur (KUL) on Malaysia Airlines or Air Asia. When transit time is longer than 8 hours it is permitted to leave the transit area
>   if:
>
> - traveling to or returning from the country which issued
>     the visa; and
> - traveling on a tour/package arranged by a company
>     registered in the country which issued the visa
>
> Transit between Main Terminal and KLIA2 is
>      also permitted. When leaving the airport transit area,
>      passports must be valid for at least 6 months from date of
>      arrival.

In other words, the only way your colleague can change terminals is if he:

- has a valid visa issued by Australia, China (People's Rep.), Chinese Taipei, Japan, Korea (Rep.), New Zealand or USA; **and**
- is travelling to/from that country on a package tour.

So, he will unfortunately Need to change the tickets

Comment: when I click timatic, it doesn't say about national of Pakistan. I know the same result would be for Pakistani national. Still +1